How to integrate over an infinite domain using TorchQuad?
I need to integrate a function over an infinite domain
right now I'm trying
def n_hat_lp(mu_0, sigma_0, mu_1, sigma_1, mu_2, sigma_2, mu_3, sigma_3, h, t):
    def integrand(x):

        l, p = x[:, 0], x[:, 1]

        return fun1(mu_0, sigma_0, mu_1, sigma_1, mu_2, sigma_2, mu_3, sigma_3, h, l, p, t)

    domain = [
        [-torch.inf, torch.inf],
        [-torch.inf, torch.inf]
    ]
    result = vegas.integrate(integrand, dim=2, N=200000, integration_domain=domain)
    return result.item()


but I'm getting many issues due to -torch.inf, torch.inf, what is the proper way to integrate over an infinite domain using TorchQuad?

Hello welcome to Stackoverflow ! Could you please post a minimal reproducible example, containing all the lines of code required to reproduce your issue ? Ideally small code that could be copy pasted to easily check it out. And what is the function you are trying to integrate ? Are you sure it is (at least theoretically) finitely integrable over your infinite domain ?
